# How do I compile mono xsp?

Tags: mono, xsp

I'm trying to build the latest XSP. I suspect this is the latest branch https://github.com/mono/xsp/tree/3.0

The problem is, `./configure` doesnt work. There isn't a configure file. There is a configure.ac but i'm not sure how to build that. The readme/install instructions doesnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local`, where `prefix` is the place to install.

Comment: Thanks. But now i get `Error: aclocal is not installed, and is required to configure`

Comment: aclocal is commonly used in building software. Please install it from your package manager (e.g. apt-get install autotools-dev)

Comment: fyi i also needed to reinstall `apt-get install automake` after installing autotools-dev